# Loading lldb breakpoint commands from a file

Tags: macos, debugging, lldb

I would like to load my breakpoint commands from a file at startup using the '-s' flag to lldb, but it does not appear to accept the usual multiline input syntax of 'br command add' (a series of commands followed by 'DONE'). Is there a way to set a multiline breakpoint command from a script file?

I have a script file 'lldb.txt' with the following:

```
br set -n ptrace
br command add 1
register write pc `$pc + 42`
cont
DONE
```

And I'm running lldb as

```
lldb -s lldb.txt MyApp
```

The part from 'register' to 'DONE' does not work as it would from the lldb command prompt.

I'm running lldb on MacOS.

Answer (score 1):

That's a bug in lldb.  It will be fixed in the next lldb release.